# TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined in /node_modules/galio-framework/src/Toast.js

Tags: react-native, expo

I am having this error when doing

```
expo start --web
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Module /APP/node_modules/galio-framework/src/Toast.js

node_modules/galio-framework/src/Toast.js:23

```
  20 |   PropTypes.string,
  21 | ]),
  22 | round: PropTypes.bool,
> 23 | style: ViewPropTypes.style,
     | ^  24 | textStyle: ViewPropTypes.style,
  25 | styles: PropTypes.any,
  26 | theme: PropTypes.any,
```

Initially I had other errors but I could solve them by adding the following code in the web section app.json

```
"web": {
  "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png",
  "build": {
    "babel": {
      "include": ["galio-framework"]
    }
  }
},
```

package.json

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^12.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.2",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.3.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "^10.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "expo-web-browser": "^9.0.0",
    "galio-framework": "^0.7.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-image-view": "^2.1.9",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-masked-text": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-material-menu": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-material-ui": "^1.30.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.6.1",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.17.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.14.13",
    "react-native-wizard": "^2.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.6.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.2",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
style: PropTypes.style
```

I have done and fixed that problem, but now I get the problem a little further down, on the line that says

```
textStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
```

How should I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the follwing code in node_modules/galio-framework/src/Toast.js
replace :

```
style: ViewPropTypes.style
```

for : `style: PropTypes.style`